# Conversion of Leads to Opportunities

Tags: community

While converting to leads to opportunities, The certain custom fields that were created did not get converted to an opportunity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you map the custom lead fields?

From Setup, click Customize | Leads | Fields | Map Lead Fields.

See https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=customize_mapleads.htm&language=en for more details.